# Flutter - how to download all images whose filenames start with

Tags: flutter, dart

Using Flutter/Dart, I am trying to download a series of png's that show rain radar images every 5 mins from FTP. The files are named with the date and UTC of when the image was taken.

For example: IDR01A.T.202106121100.png

IDR01A.T. is constant, then it's followed by YYYYMMDDHHMM

I'm stumped how to get all images that start with the desired ID e.g. IDR01A
(Note there are many different images with different ID's in the folder). Any help appreciated on how to download all files starting with "IDR01A" for example.

[image: ftp image listing]

Comment: You are trying to download from a server? Does the server provide a list of files? Otherwise you are out of luck because to download a file you have to know its name.

Comment: Yes, downloading from a public ftp server. I'll check to see if the server has a list of files - thanks

Comment: There are various ftp client packages for dart. For instance https://pub.dev/packages/ftpconnect

Comment: Thanks. The problem is not knowing the file names. I've found a project on github where they have a formula for working out the file names. I'll have to see if I can decode it to figure out how they do it. https://github.com/caseyfw/bom-gif PHP. And in python https://github.com/bremor/bom_radar